# trying to get apache mod_stats '/server-status' to work

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

mod_status is a apache module that lets you see the status of apache. After its switched on, it can be accessed at server.com/server-status, however I cant access it because of the mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file. below is the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} othersite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://server.com/$1 [R=301]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

when I disable above, http://server.com/server-status works. This is probably a common issue with mod_rewrite, but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with CMS software that handle all non-file URLs.
You may modify the rewrite block to include an explicit condition on `/server-status`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following documentation ([Apache Virtual Host documentation - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)) and reconfigure it so that you'll use VirtualHost for your domain and leave welcome page alone, this way you'll be able to use it for server-status. That would be a correct way of doing things anyway...

Comment: do you know anything about plesk? Its not as straight forward as doing that. I cant edit default virtual host. It has to have a domain/subscription. I tried setting up a dummy host and making that default but it didnt work. Is there an alternative ie rewriting the .htaccess file to ignore a URL.